# Active Integration with Pentaho 5.2 Community Edition

Tags: ldap, pentaho

I have MS Active Directory setup on Windows 2008 R2. I created two groups Admins and Devs under the default group Users that comes in default. I added two users in Admins group with Administrator rights and one user in Devs group. I am trying to login with admininstrator user 'kishank' but I am getting the following error:

[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1 ]

I googled upon this error which says invalid user or password. Here's the link: [It gives description about error code 49 **DSID 0C0903A9**. It says that the error only occurs on MS AD servers.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGRP3_1.1.0/com.ibm.puresystems.appsys.1700.doc/iwd/tst_trbl_ldap_messages.html?lang=en)

I also read somewhere that I should uncheck "Password never expires" checkbox for users but no luck.

My configuration files are as below:

**applicationContext-security-ldap.properties**

```
contextSource.providerUrl=ldap\://host:port/cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
contextSource.userDn=domain\kishank
contextSource.password=pass

userSearch.searchBase=CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
userSearch.searchFilter=(sAMAccountName={0})

populator.convertToUpperCase=false
populator.groupRoleAttribute=cn
populator.groupSearchBase=cn=Devs,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
populator.groupSearchFilter=(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=({0}))
populator.rolePrefix=
populator.searchSubtree=true

allAuthoritiesSearch.roleAttribute=cn
allAuthoritiesSearch.searchBase=cn=Devs,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
allAuthoritiesSearch.searchFilter=(objectClass=group)

allUsernamesSearch.usernameAttribute=sAMAccountName
allUsernamesSearch.searchBase=cn=Devs,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
allUsernamesSearch.searchFilter=objectClass=person

adminRole=cn=Admins,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
adminUser=sAMAccountName=kishank,cn=Users
```

**repository.spring**

```
singleTenantAdminDefaultUserName=kishank
singleTenantAdminUserName=kishank
singleTenantAdminDefaultAuthorityName=Administrator
singleTenantAdminAuthorityName=Administrator
repositoryAdminUsername=pentahoRepoAdmin
singleTenantAuthenticatedAuthorityName=Devs
singleTenantAnonymousAuthorityName=Anonymous
superAdminAuthorityName=SysAdmin
superAdminUserName=super
systemTenantAdminUserName=system
systemTenantAdminPassword=cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Please ignore 'enter code here' text in the question.